# map two array column to each other and make columns from one of the arrays colum Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using pos from core NLP and I am getting result like below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  
import com.databricks.spark.corenlp.functions._  

import sqlContext.implicits._  

val input = Seq(  
  (1, "<xml>Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university.</xml>")  
).toDF("id", "text")  
val output = input.select(explode(ssplit('text)).as('sen)).select('sen, tokenize('sen).as('words), pos('sen).as('posTags))
```

the result is following

```
    +----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+  
    |sen                                           |words                                                 |posatag                        |  
    +----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+  
    |Stanford University is located in California .|[Stanford, University, is, located, in, California, .]|[NNP, NNP, VBZ, JJ, IN, NNP, .]|
    |It is a great university .                    |[It, is, a, great, university, .]                     |[PRP, VBZ, DT, JJ, NN, .]      |  
    +----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I want to get the word column and postag column mapped.

```
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+ 
|    sen                                       |    words                                                 | posatag                       |     NNP                          |  VBZ   |more columns form postag |  
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+  
|Stanford University is located in California .|[Stanford, University, is, located, in, California, .]    |[NNP, NNP, VBZ, JJ, IN, NNP, .]|[Stanford, University,California] | [is]   |                         |  
|It is a great university .                    |[It, is, a, great, university, .]                         |[PRP, VBZ, DT, JJ, NN, .]      | []                               | [is]   |                         |  
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Please help me to get this.

Comment: please format the code first.

Comment: your results looks very ugly, we can't help you if we cant see what you want

Comment: now result looks fine i think

Answer (score 1):

I resolved to above solution in a long way.
first I zipped word using following udf

```
def zippPosToWords=udf((list1:Seq[String],list2:Seq[String]) => {
   val zipList = list1 zip list2
   val groupBy_list = zipList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues {_.map {case (_, b)=> b}}
   groupBy_list
}
)
```

then I created a column with above data

```
val output1=output.withColumn("postowords", zippPosToWords(col("posTags"), col("words")))
```

then explode this to columns.

```
val finaldf = output1.select(col("*"),explode('postowords))
```

it will give you the a table structure like following:

```
 +----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+ 
|    sen                                       |    words                                                 | posatag                       |     NNP                          |  VBZ   |more columns form postag |  
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+  
|Stanford University is located in California .|[Stanford, University, is, located, in, California, .]    |[NNP, NNP, VBZ, JJ, IN, NNP, .]|[Stanford, University,California] | [is]   |                         |  
|It is a great university .                    |[It, is, a, great, university, .]                         |[PRP, VBZ, DT, JJ, NN, .]      | []                               | [is]   |                         |  
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Hope it will help somebody.